# Struct definition for linked lists in c++

Tags: c++

While solving questions related to linked lists in C++, the struct definition for implementation of list was given as follows.

```
Struct node{
  int data;
  node *next;
  node(int x) : data(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

what is the significance of 3rd line :
" node(int x) : data(x), next(NULL) {} ".

Accessing it as a function is giving runtime error. Please share some resources where I can get a better understanding of the topic.

P.S.- I have just shifted from C to C++.

Comment: There is a list of good C++ books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Don't assume that C and C++ are almost the same language.

Comment: Be sincere to the former Java developer. I also had this question in the past.

Comment: Congratulations for leaving Java behind and for taking up C++. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node(int x) : data(x), next(NULL) {}`

- This is the constructor of `node`. It creates a `node` and initializes the member `data` with value `x`.
- Read more [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

If you are from python background, then it is same as

```
class Node: 
    
    def __init__(self, x): 
        self.data = x
        self.next = None
```

struct is same as class except everything is public by default in cpp strict. struct is an object in cpp, so it needs a constructor.

> Please share some resources where I can get a better understanding of the topic.

- Start [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects).
- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/c
- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

Comment: You didn't say anything about the `next` data member.

Comment: My bad, updated